# Actionscript 2 Proper way to define function on MovieClip

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

I'm trying to write a function on a MovieClip, and call it from the root clip. What works fine in ActionScript 3 doesn't seem to be working properly in ActionScript 2.

Frame 1 of the `_root` MovieClip:

```
var newMovieClip:MovieClip = _root.attachMovie('Notification', id, 0);
newMovieClip.SetNotificationText("Test text");
```

Frame 1 of the `Notification` MovieClip:

```
function SetNotificationText(inputText : String){
    notificationText.text = inputText;
}
```

The result is that the MovieClip is created but the text is not changed.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add functions to a MovieClip in AS2, you need to use one of these methods:

1. Add the method to the prototype of MovieClip:

   ```
   MovieClip.prototype.SetNotificationText = function(inputText:String):Void
   {
       if(this["notificationText"] !== undefined)
       {
           // If we're going to use the prototype, at least do some checks
           // to make sure the caller MovieClip has the text field we expect.
           this.notificationText.text = inputText;
       }
   }

   newMovieClip.SetNotificationText("Test text");
   ```
2. Make the MovieClip and argument of the function:

   ```
   function SetNotificationText(mc:MovieClip, inputText:String):Void
   {
       mc.notificationText.text = inputText;
   }

   SetNotificationText(newMovieClip, "Test text");
   ```
3. Add the method directly to the newly created MovieClip:

   ```
   var newMovieClip:MovieClip = _root.attachMovie('Notification', id, 0);

   newMovieClip.SetNotificationText(inputText:String):Void
   {
       notificationText.text = inputText;
   }

   newMovieClip.SetNotificationText("Test text");
   ```

Option 2 is best overall - it's the cleanest and avoids overhead of creating a new function for every new MovieClip. It also avoids messing around with the prototype, which at best should be used to add generic methods, like a `removeItem()` method on `Array`.